# What does $dx$ mean in an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

$\int_0^{1} 3{x^3}\,{dx} $

$\int3{x^3}\,{dx} $

Both the definite and indefinite integrals have the same mark in their ends, ${dx}$.
The latter one's ${dx}$ would mean an infinitely small width of a rectangle. Then what does  ${dx}$ in the former mean?

Comment: It means "you're integrating with respect to $x$." I think you're mixing up "former" and "latter", too.

Comment: You are integrating with respect to x

Comment: it means your integration variable is $x$, for example if your function contains $x$ and $t$ then $dx$ means that $t$ is considered as a constant and $x$ as the variable. Of course, if there is only $x$ in the expression of $f$ so $dx$ apprears to be meaningless.

Comment: I also see it in some cases mean "This is where the integral stops", so that in for instance $\int 3x\:dx +4x^3$, you're only supposed to integrate $3x$. However, not everyone is consistent about this, and especially physicists like to write $\int dx\: 3x$ some times.